# Faster way to find corrupt files on Linux

Tags: linux, corruption

I need a rapid method to list corrupted files on my HDD.

So far I tries these commands in a 6.7GiB folder before doing this on the root of the data filesystem :

```bash
$ time $(which grep) -a -r . ./ 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep -w error 
grep: ./bug_de_l_an_2000.mp4: Input/output error

real    1m40.097s
user    0m18.804s
sys 0m8.052s
$ time $(which find) . -type f -exec cat {} 2>&1 >/dev/null \; | grep -w error
cat: ./bug_de_l_an_2000.mp4: Input/output error

real    1m39.405s
user    0m0.268s
sys 0m7.396s
$ time $(which find) . -type f -exec dd if={} of=/dev/null 2>&1 \; | grep -w error
dd: error reading ‘./bug_de_l_an_2000.mp4’: Input/output error

real    1m12.183s
user    0m6.856s
sys 0m20.092s
$ time $(which find) . -type f -exec pv {} 2>&1 >/dev/null \; | grep -w error
pv: ‘./bug_de_l_an_2000.mp4’: Input/output error

real    1m39.572s
user    0m0.392s
sys 0m11.708s
```

Do you know faster method(s) ?

Comment: How much faster do you expect to get? If you have a spinning disk, it's going to be 40 or 50 seconds just to get it off the disk for reading which makes your 3rd command pretty close to that. Whatever you do you will likely be limited by the disk speed since the work you are looking to do is pretty simple.

Comment: @user1794469 I believe you're right, I'll just stick to the `dd` solution, then.